# Functions have similar graphs

Tags: functions

I graphed the two functions $y=x^2\sin\left(\frac{x}{50}\right)$ and $y=\frac{1}{50}x^3$ and I noticed they have extremely similar graphs from $-50 < x <50$. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Have you compared the Taylor series and computed its radius of convergence?

Comment: What is a Taylor series?

Comment: You can find [the definition](http://bit.ly/2h3XOaz) in this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: It's because $\sin(x)$ is very close to $x$ when $x$ is close to $0$. This happens since the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ starts as

$$x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+...$$

For a longer and more in-depth answer, see Olivier Oloa's.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. By differentiation, one may prove that
$$
u-\frac{u^3}6\le\sin u\le u,\qquad u \in [0,1]
$$ giving
$$
\frac{x^3}{50}-\frac{x^5}{750000}\le x^2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{50}\right)\le \frac{x^3}{50}, \quad -1<\frac{x}{50}<1
$$ or

> $$
> \left| x^2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{50}\right)-\frac{x^3}{50}\right|\le \left|\frac{x^5}{750000}\right|, \quad -1<\frac{x}{50}<1.
> $$